# Create Boxplot in without Whiskers

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot the image above without the whiskers, I'd like the bars to have full size, is it possible to do so? I know there's a parameter called showfliers that I've set to false, but is there anything I can do to have my bar on full size, w/o having the whiskers?

```
sns.boxplot(y='Total', x='Month', 
             data=df, 
             hue='Value',
             showfliers=False,
             showcaps=False)
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with using whis = 0 is that is that then the bar will go up to 6.2, the whisker will be out, but the bar won't extend up to there...

Comment: So you want the "box" of the boxplot to extend all the way to where the whiskers would normally go?

Comment: Correct, that's what I want